# Different shades of Transparent colors for Lego part 30602

Tags: colour

I have two 30602 lego parts that look slightly different. The top one is "transparent black" but the bottom is a bit darker. Does anybody know what's going on here? I'm trying to identify which set is the bottom part coming from.

[image: white background]

[image: back side]

Comment: I'm not at all certain, but is it possible the top one is just Transparent (Trans Clear), and the **bottom** one is the Transparent Black? Could you re-take the photo on a white background?

Comment: This is, most likely, a production inconsistency or caused by aging.